# Find PDF of $Y=-\frac{1}{2} \cdot \ln(X)$ given $f_X(x)=3x^2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I need to find the PDF of $Y=-\frac{1}{2} \cdot \ln(X)$  given $f_X(x)=3x^2$.

Can someone help me and give a clear explanation for what you should do for solving problems like this?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know how to solve problems like this is by considering the cumulative distribution function. I assume $X$ is distributed over $[0,1]$. Then:

$$F_X(x) : = P(X < x) = \int_0^x 3t^2\, dt = x^3$$

We compute the cdf of $Y$:
$$P(Y<y) = P(-\tfrac12 \ln X < y) = P(\ln X>-2y) = P(X > e^{-2y}) = 1-F_X(e^{-2y}).$$

Can you complete it from here?

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer. Could you explain what the next steps are?

Comment: No problem @LucasBagge. Could you tell me what you're specifically having trouble with? I've given an expression for $F_Y(y)$ in terms of $F_X(y)$, which is defined earlier in the answer. Do you know how to get the pdf from the cdf?

Comment: Okay so the $1.F_X(e^{-2y})$ is the CDF expressions for Y? But I would like to know how to get the pdf from the cdf as you mention?

Comment: The pdf is the derivative of the cdf. For example, if the cdf is $F(x) = P(X<x) = e^{-2x}$, the pdf is $f(x) = F'(x) = -2e^{-2x}$.